# Vue.js date off by one

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My code in its most basic form on [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/hiyebutugi/1/edit?html,js,output).

I have dates stored as `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` that need to be displayed as `MM/DD/YYYY` and edited as `YYYY-MM-DD`, as that's what HTML's date input requires. Everything seemingly works, except the **first time** I modify the day, the reflected date is one day earlier. Subsequent changes are thus one off.

Initial state:

[image: Initial state]

First change:

[image: First change]

Any subsequent change:

[image: Any subsequent change]

Comment: Could you share some code?

Comment: I'm in Germany, the date input shown the date in format DD.MM.YYYY for me, becuase of my browsers (Chrome btw.) locale. And your code works fine for me.

Comment: If it's working in Germany (GMT + 2) and it is not working for me in Tennessee (GMT - 6) then I would venture to say your issue is localization-related.

Comment: I might be worth looking at something like https://github.com/brockpetrie/vue-moment

Comment: This is bound to be a difference between using a UTC time in some places and a local timezone time in others.

Answer (score 0):

I extracted the utc dates then was able to get the date working without it being off by one day.

Something similar to:

```html
<input
          type="date"
          name="startDate"
          :value="startDate && startDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]"
          @input="startDate = getDateClean($event.target.valueAsDate)"
          autocomplete="off"
          class="form-control"
        />
```

```js
method:{
  getDateClean(currDate: Date) {
  // need to convert to UTC to get working input filter
  console.log(currDate);
  let month: number | string = currDate.getUTCMonth() + 1;
  if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
  let day: number | string = currDate.getUTCDate();
  if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;
  const dateStr =
    currDate.getUTCFullYear() + "-" + month + "-" + day + "T00:00:00";
  console.log(dateStr);
  const d = new Date(dateStr);
  console.log(d);
  return d;
  }
}
```

See running example from answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63838211/2875452;